# A function like sin x with a bit difference

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a function as follows:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \cases{
-x-1 & if $-2<x<0$\\
x-1& if $0<x<2$}
 ; f(0)=-1 ;    f(x+4)=f(x)
\end{equation}

I want to write $f(x)$ as polynomial functions, not unit step function, if possible.

Comment: There's a discontinuity at $x = 0$, so unless I am not interpreting this question correctly, the answer would be _no_.

Comment: It is not important. It is better that we have f(0)=-1.

Comment: It _is_ important: $0$ is not in the domain of $f$, so you do not have $f(0) = -1$. Is it intentional that there are strict inequalities about $0$?

Comment: Consider that $f(0)=-1$. Add this condition to your function.

Comment: I eddited the question to be easier

Comment: What you are describing is a triangular wave. You can represent it with an infinity series of sin/cos functions but not sure whats what you are after. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave

Comment: So, we cannot write it as summation of finite elementary function?

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the link is useful.

Comment: Polynomial function is differentiable. But given function is not differentiable at $x=2k$.

Comment: Not polynomials in the normal sense. If you allow functions like floor or ceiling or mod or absolute value then you can do it.

Comment: @IanMiller Would you please do it? floor or mod or absolute functions are possible for me.

Comment: Or with amplitude $a$ and period $p$: $$f(x)=\frac{2a}{\pi}\arcsin\left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}x\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. The link was useful and informative. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a triangular wave with amplitude of 1 and period of 4. Such a function can not be created from polynomials as it has a non-continuous derivative whereas the derivative of any polynomial is always continuous.

It can be expressed as the sum of an infinity number of sin/cos functions via Fourier techniques.

Using trigonometry it can be expressed (with amplitude $a$ and period $p$) as:
$$f(x)=\frac{2a}{\pi}\arcsin\left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}x\right)\right)$$

Using floor and absolute value functions you can also do: 
$$f(x)=\left|\frac{2}{a}\left(t-a\bigg\lfloor\frac{x}{a}+\frac12\bigg\rfloor\right)\right|$$

Further reading (and where I got the functions from): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave